# Python : Selecting words out of text

Tags: python

So I'm having problem with a small project I'm working on, the problem is on line 10 and 18. I can't trigger line 48 for some reason and I can't understand why? Also I have another question, which is why is it that when I type in something random that shouldn't be acknowledged by the program, like for example when the program says "Please state your problem" and I were to type in "iajsdb" why doesn't the program end there? Instead it selects one of the results like "Is the internet slow or the phone overall?". Also yes I know the code is very messy and this is a snippet of what I wrote if more is needed to sort out the problem then I'll be happy to post more. Many thanks.

```
        #Twig2 (iPhone/2g/problem/wet)
    elif "wet" in iproblem2g.lower():
        print ("The chances that your phone will recover from water damage is extremly minimal. You may wish to go to a proffesional and see if any data can be restored, otehrwise you will most likely need to buy a new phone.")
        applestore = raw_input ("Would you like to find an Apple store near you? ")
        if "yes" or "sure" or "okay" in applestore:
            webbrowser.open("http://www.apple.com/retail/")
        else:
            print("Troubleshooting complete.")

    elif "no wifi" or "can't connect" or "cant connect" in iproblem2g.lower():
        print("If you cannot connect to your local wifi network then follow these steps:")
        print("1. Make sure you have a strong signal")
        print("2. Make sure your wifi is actually on in your settings")
        print("3. Make sure your wifi network is visible to the public and not invisible.")
        print("If none of these steps helped then consider going to your local phone repair shop and getting it checked up.")

            #Twig4 (iPhone/problem/slow)
    elif "slow" or "lag" in iproblem2g.lower():
        slow = raw_input ("Is the internet slow or the phone overall? ")
        if "net" or "web" in slow:
            print ("Make sure that your slow connection isn't caused by a weak signal.")
            nettips = raw_input ("Would you like to be redirected to a page with tips to speed up your internet? ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `if` correctly. You should use:

```
elif "no wifi" in iproblem2g.lower() or "can't connect"  in iproblem2g.lower() or "cant connect" in iproblem2g.lower():
elif "slow" in iproblem2g.lower() or "lag" in iproblem2g.lower():
```

And so on (repeat the condition, the `or` makes it evaluate to `True` all the time regardless of your input)...